# how do i implement 'sign in with google' on my site using django. i have tried but it gives error 'Google no longer supports OAuth 1.0'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

```html
    SOCIAL_AUTH_ADMIN_USER_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                                         'username']

    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='73632804'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='2331538fcfe91efccb038'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '50599836-ke08o3tjh2aa6q1ie4d2g4jpr3p26.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '1mj8Y5xxZQ2ZQXMq'
    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '50599836-    ke08o3tjh2aa6q17ie4d2g4jpr3p26.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '1mj8Y5xx2ZQXMq'

    try:
    from example.local_settings import *
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

i have used the source [github](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) and
 entire code is [here](http://pastebin.com/TZuTGH6P)
 any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend'` from your `AUTHENTIFICATION_BACKENDS`, its using OAuth 1.0 which is deprecated, quoting [Google identity platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuthForWebApps) :

> Important: OAuth 1.0 was officially deprecated on April 20, 2012, and is no longer supported. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.